# Where has Android Developer Console gone

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

A while back I wrote an Android app and I used to monitor the sales activity at https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home#

The app never sold much, so I haven't checked it in a while.
I just went to check it and that URL is no longer active.

I assume some new URL or service has replaced that.

Can you tell me how to view my sales info (# of downloads, devices, returns, etc)

Comment: Thanks. Post it as an answer so I can check you up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the /Home# at the end

https://play.google.com/apps/publish